# Is Partitioner required for single reducer in map reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have just begin learning hadoop. I understood that Partitioner decides whick key-value pairs are to be sent to which reducers. My question is Partitioner required if there is only one reducer?

I saw similar question in stackover fow itself but i was unable to understand answer still.

Comment: There's a default partitioner, so yes it's required. FWIW, plain MapReduce programming isn't done that much and you'll often have much more than one Reducer unless doing a collection or aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Yes,The Partitioner redirects the keyvalue pairs of map output to particular reducers by calculating default hash function on mapout key or defined in the customized partition key,when multiple reducers are in place. If only one reducer,all the key values to be transferred to same reducer,though Partitioner exists. The default Partitioner always exists in mapreducer flow.